# Dynamically sending data while read or reload Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to send some parameter from client side while reading the data from server side. I am using Javascript. My code for transport part od dataSource is as follows:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/daily/statusList",
        data: [{
            id :  $("#txtId").val(),
            resId : $("#txtResId").val(),
            duration : $("#duration").val() 
        }]                                      
    }
},
```

I am not getting any of this on server side. I am setting them from input textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Data is should be single object not an array.

e.g.

```
transport: {
    read: {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/daily/statusList",
        data: {
            id :  $("#txtId").val(),
            resId : $("#txtResId").val(),
            duration : $("#duration").val() 
        }                                      
    }
},
```